# Retrieving single row within transaction hangs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I run several SQLs ( select, update and insert ) within single database connection and transaction, one of the SQLs is to retrieve the balance of an account

```
select top 1 balance from sample_table where account_id={accountId} order by id desc
```

This SQL hangs only and only if there are no records actually in the table "sample_table" for the account {accountId} , otherwise it works normally.
Hangs means it waits until a timeout exception error occurs, and during this 'wait' , executing the SQL from Sql Server management studio also hangs.

I'm using Sql Server 2008

thanks

ِEDIT:

After multiple attempts to perform same action, it does work and all the records are inserted properly and then the app works like the charm after that.
Restore the database, then the issue is back again.

Comment: Without seeing your schema it's hard to tell; any primary keys, or indexes on the table? I would assume `id` is primary maybe with auto increment and account_id would be a foreign key to where that is and being a primary key?

Comment: ID is a primary key
account_id is indexed

Comment: Go to the Activity Monitor in Management Studio and kill off the processes associated with that particular database. There may have been transactions opened and never closed... it could have happened on code side and this will give you a clean slate. Check all your insert/update statements to make sure they're properly getting committed/closed when they finish othwise a lock can occur and cause issues as well. You mentioned this is just part of the statement, can you post the rest if so?

Comment: if possible, better place your full code which was used to fetch the records, which helps to figure out issue clearly

Comment: I already checked the activity monitor and there is only one process which is the current process that is accessing this record! And reviewed the connections in detail, and I'm sure it's not the cause because if it was the cause then it would also hang when there are records in the table. Note that in the same connection and transaction I insert records into this table

Comment: Then the table is more than likely locked which is mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: If it's locked then all the queries on this table would fail, so no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed after rebuilding the table, basically executing this SQL:

```
alter table sample_table rebuild
```